# UIAlertView replacement

Tags: iphone, uialertview, ipad

It seems that I am always fighting with UIAlertView to make it do what I want.  I'm done fighting - are there any robust UIAlertView replacements with the following features, or will I need to write my own?:

- ability to customize the alert-view size/position
- ability to change the layout of the
  buttons (stacked vs. side-by-side)
- ability to prompt users for input via UITextField or UITextView
- resizing / repositioning behavior
  when the keyboard appears
- ability to have a UITextView for
  scrolling text
- pixel-perfect copy of UIAlertView for
  basic display
- ideally interface compatible with
  UIAlertView - i.e. it is a drop-in-replacement.

I've found a few blog and stackoverflow posts which implement customizations on a UIAlertView - this is NOT what I want.  Nor do I want a guide on how to implement a custom AlertView -- I know how, I just want to find one that is already community maintained.  I want a ground-up replacement that is safe for App Store submission and future-proof against UIAlertView changes (yes, I've been burnt...)

Please respond with comments if you have suggestions for other desirable features.

Comment: @skaffman - how come you removed the iphone-ui tag?

Comment: Perhaps because it's not really a tag that's used at all (0 questions) and so it wouldn't add anything?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I searched high and low for a prefab UIAlertView project that offered the features I was looking for.  I'm sure they exist -- I've seen apps with great alerts.  Their authors must not be sharing - which is totally fine, I understand.

So I wrote my own.  TSAlertView is a ground-up implementation of a modal alert view that is interface-compatible with UIAlertView.  In terms of visual look, while it is not a pixel-perfect copy, it comes very close.  The features it offers are basically what I outlined in the original question:

- ability to set the display-width and max-height of the alert view.  This allows me to have nicer looking alerts on iPad.
- ability to specify the layout of the buttons (stacked vs. side-by-side), even if there are only two buttons.  This always bothered me with UIAlertView -- if I had two buttons they were always placed side-by-side.  A big problem if the button text didn't fit.
- ability to prompt users for input via a UITextField.  Once in a while you just need a quick and dirty way to prompt the user to enter something.
- resizing / repositioning behavior when the keyboard appears.  (happens when prompting for user-input)
- ability to have a UITextView for scrolling text.  Can explicitly set this option instead of relying on UIAlertView to swap in a UITextView for long text.
- near pixel-perfect copy of UIAlertView for basic display.
- support for custom backgrounds
- is interface compatible with UIAlertView - i.e. it is a drop-in-replacement.

I've used a handful of great open-source projects in my code in the last year.  My two favorites are [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) and [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController), each hosted at github.  I decided to share TSAlertView in the same manner.

https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView

The initial implementation surely has some bugs.  I haven't used it in a shipping project yet, but I am using it in my current project to be completed in a few weeks.  If you want to try using it yourself, please feel free.  Post any issues on github, or better yet, submit a fix.

Enjoy!

Here are some screenshots showing **1)** 2 stacked buttons **2)** input capability  **3)** explicit width setting

[image: showing 2 stacked buttons here]  [image: showing input capability]  [image: showing wide-layout]

Comment: Hey TomSwift,Thank you for that great project. I was about to start such a project until I came over your TSAlertView. Really cool. I'm now using it in one of my apps. ;-)

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you for an excellent and easy-to-use open-source replacement for something that's harder than it needs to be in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Smart Alert View](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Smart-Alert-View), it's open-source.

Comment: thanks for the link.  I got scared of this one when I scanned the code and found this:  - (void) ResizeAlertView: (UIAlertView *) alertView  {
 CGFloat height = view_.frame.size.height + 110; 
 alertView.frame = CGRectMake(15.0f, (460-height)/2 ,300.0f, height);
}

Comment: also, my preference is for something not derived from UIAlertView.

Comment: You are going to either have to build your own implementation of a UIAlertView (which is more af a nightmare than customizing one), or just customize one, it's not as difficult as you would expect.

Comment: i disagree that, given my parameters, writing one from scratch is more difficult than customizing UIAlertView in a future-proof way.

Comment: which is basically what I said.

Comment: I disagree that the world is round. It doesn't mean I'm right.

Answer (score 0):

Check my own Alert view replacement - get app here. https://github.com/FeminaErnest/GeekyFemi.      Good luck